# How to assign key combination WinBtn + Arrows for End, Home, PgUp, PgDown on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, kubuntu

I've bought new laptop Asus ZenBook UX433F and on it combinations Fn+Arrows (which was equialent Home, End, PgUp, PgDown on my previous laptop) assigned to non comfortable for work keys. So I tried to find solution for my problem, but didn't find any simple working solution for key combintaion key remapping. All advices was about to remap only single key. According to question - why I asking about WinBtn. Because Fn button is not detectin by xev utility. Thanks in advance!

P.S. The most ineresting variant for me decribed in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65434/map-superleftright-to-home-end/65923#65923) But I got an error:

```
Error:            Illegal include statement "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)
+mysymbols(super_arrows_home_end)"
                  Ignored Error:            Can't find file "complete " for types include
                  Exiting

 Abandoning keytypes file "(null)"
```

My actual `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd`:

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete +mytypes(super_level2)"       };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"        };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev) +mysymbols(super_arrows_home_end)"      };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. The [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) utility helps me. 
A little problem with macros occured when I try to select text from current position to end\start of line. For fixing it I just added new macroses with `Shift` button. Screens of my setting attached.

[Settings for END button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6C2r.png)

[Settings for HOME button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtqUO.png)

[Settings for END with selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAqQC.png)

[Settings for HOME with selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msiPb.png)